# luamplib: global definitions without inheritance

Tags: luatex, metapost, luamplib

Is there a way of globally defining metapost macros using `luamplib` and without enabling inheritance for `mplibcode` code blocks?  It seems possible since it appears that this is what `luamplib` does when setting the format.

I'm running MikTex on Windows, so the `metafun` format [doesn't work](https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/15).  As such, I'm inputting `mp-tool.mpiv` for each `mplibcode` block using `\everymplib`.  This works fine I guess, but it seems pretty inefficient.  I looked at the `luamplib.cfg` file, but this seems only to take latex macros, and thus any metapost definitions would need to be enclosed in an `mplibcode` block, and inheritance enabled for them to be available in further blocks.

I could simply enable inheritance, but as I understand it this applies globally and so I worry that doing so could lead to errors that are difficult for me to diagnose (I'm just learning).

Equivalently, is there a way to have subsequent code blocks inherit definitions from some given code block, but not others?

A "MWE":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luamplib}

% Is there somewhere that I can place this code so that it does not
% have to be read for each and every mplibcode block and without resorting
% to global inheritance between all code blocks.  Something like
% \mplibsetformat{} but \mplibsetdefinitions{}.
\everymplib{
    vardef mympfun (expr a,b) = 
    save pta,ptb;
    pta:= xpart a;
    ptb:= ypart b;
    draw origin--(pta,ptb);
    enddef;
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
    u:=1cm;
    pair a,b;
    a:=u*(1,0);
    b:=u*(0,1);
    
    beginfig(0);
        mympfun(a,b);
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\begin{mplibcode}
    u:=1cm;
    pair a,b;
    a:=u*(-1,0);
    b:=u*(0,3);
    
    beginfig(0);
        mympfun(a,b);
    endfig;
\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just use `\everymplib`, you basically can't get around reparsing this. Even MetaPost "formats" work that way: Some versions ago, the traditional format system was dropped and now every format has to be parsed every time it is used. This sounds bad, but MetaPost is quite fast, so it shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: @Marcel Oh wow...alright. Out of curiosity: would it then be more efficient to enable inheritance and say input an `mp` file at the start of the document rather than using `\everymplib`?  Or is inheritance essentially doing the same thing and loading the contents of all earlier environments for each subsequent environment?  Either way, this is a perfectly good answer if you want to make it one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of V2.22, `luamplib` provides a new way to do this: named instances. So your choices now are three:

1. use `everymplib` and don't worry about whether this is efficient or not.
2. use `\mplibcodeinherit{enable}` and treat each `mplibcode` environment as a continuation of the previous ones.  The only thing to watch out for here, is to make a clear distinction between variables that you want to inherit and variables that you want to be local.  So you might consider a naming convention in your code -- such as initial Capital for global variables.  And if you want to be sure that you are not inheriting a value from before you can re-declare them using `numeric` or `pair` or whatever, which will remove any previous value.
3. use instance names on `mplibcode` environments.  This is described in [the  manual, on p.4](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib).  The idea is that you write

   ```
   \begin{mplibcode}[common]
   % your MP figure, with useful definitions
   \end{mplibcode}
   ```

   and then a bit later you can have a regular environment without the name

   ```
   \begin{mplibcode}
   % MP figure that is completely independent
   \end{mplibcode}
   ```

   and then another that shares things with the first one

   ```
   \begin{mplibcode}[common]
   % your MP figure, that shares everything with earlier
   % "common" instances
   \end{mplibcode}
   ```

   You can use as many separate names as you like (apparently).

Comment: I forgot about this question, thanks for taking the time to answer.